# Matomo: try to set title categories by setDocumentTitle("testDirectory/testTitle");

Tags: api, title, tracking, matomo

According to
https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_62/
I added to my Matomo JS-Snippet this line:

```
var newTitle =  "testDirectory/testTitle";
_paq.push(["setDocumentTitle",  newTitle]);
```

But the titles shown in Matomo are not grouped (Screenshot):
[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Or maybe is grouping feature not supported by older Matomo (I'm using Matomo 3.13.6).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It only works if I set

```
[General]
action_title_category_delimiter = ::
```

in config/config.ini.php

Of course I have to use

```
var newTitle =  "testDirectory :: testTitle";
_paq.push(["setDocumentTitle",  newTitle]);
```

Conclusion: '/' is not default delimiter.

after that

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the FAQ was updated at https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_62/
By default the default delimiter is empty so the feature is disabled by default (this was changed a while ago)